# Blackberry - animation in a same BitmapField during some process

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, animation

Actually i want to show an animated picture motion in PopupScreen when some process is going on in the background like password checking or nwtwork connection. I dont know where to call the repaint or invalidate method and how to implement thread . Please write a simple program with required code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [KB article](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800345/How_To_-_Display_an_animated_GIF.html?nodeid=1405903&vernum=0) on animaged GIFs? It is probably a good place to start.

Comment: No not the gif image... few number of png files i want to display in same BitmapField, after certain interval like  after half sec. How will i do that in thread using runnable interface

Comment: It would be similar, except without the convenience of a multiple frame GIF you would draw successive PNG images rather than successive GIF frames.

Answer (score 0):

May be usefull:
[Is there a way to show a “Loading” dialog with animation in Blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801161/is-there-a-way-to-show-a-loading-dialog-with-animation-in-blackberry)