# show indeterminate spinng hourglass when user click in a button

Tags: blackberry

In my application there is button field, when user click it, application communicate to a webserver, I want to insert a  dynamic spinning "Hour Glass" at that time ....If any one knows the solution  plz help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope u want a wait screen feature

try these links:

http://www.naviina.eu/wp/blackberry/loading-class-for-blackberry/

[Blackberry - Loading/Wait screen with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801161/blackberry-loading-wait-screen-with-animation)