# Display splash screen during app installation on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I've been looking at several BlackBerry forums but wasn't able to find any reference if this is possible or not.

Comment: Well, app installation is a system action and at this point your app is NOT installed yet and thus can not be run to provide any sort of splash.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of following:

- [Blackberry - Loading/Wait screen with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801161/blackberry-loading-wait-screen-with-animation)
- [loading-class-for-blackberry](http://www.naviina.eu/wp/blackberry/loading-class-for-blackberry/)
- [BB Splash Screen](http://blog.bayestech.com/?p=49)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create an app that would run a loading screen while it installed the final target app, AFAIK