# Blackberry java, Open dialog from non UI thread using synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, blackberry

I want to open a dialog from a separate thread, but when using the `synchronized` way, I get an error.

If I use the method `invokeAndWait` everything works fine, however I don't understand why I can't use `synchronized`.

Here is the code I call in my screen:

```
public void Login() {

        new HttpRequestDispatcher("http://www.google.com", "GET", this) {
            public void onSuccess(byte[] baos, String contentType) {
                synchronized(UiApplication.getEventLock()){
                    Dialog.alert("Cooooooool....");
                }
            }
            public void onFail(String message){
                synchronized(UiApplication.getEventLock()){
                    Dialog.alert(message);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Here is the HttpRequestDispatcherThread:

```
public abstract class HttpRequestDispatcher extends Thread {

    String url;
    String method;
    Screen scr;

    public HttpRequestDispatcher(String url, String method, Screen scr) {
        this.url = url;
        this.method = method;
        this.scr = scr;
    }

    public abstract void onFail(String message);
    public abstract void onSuccess(byte[] baos, String contentType);
    public void beforeSend() {}
    public void onComplete() {}

    public void run() {

        beforeSend();

        try {

            HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
            connection.setRequestMethod(method);

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                onFail(connection.getResponseMessage());
                connection.close();
                return;
            }

            String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-type");
            int contentLength = (int) connection.getLength();
            if (contentLength < 0)
                contentLength = 10000;

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            InputStream responseData = connection.openInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
            int bytesRead = responseData.read(buffer);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = responseData.read(buffer);
            }

            baos.close();
            connection.close();

            onComplete();
            onSuccess(baos.toByteArray(), contentType);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error in the simulator: "JVM Error 104 Uncought: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

Comment: Which the error you get in case using `synchronized` keyword?

Comment: I edited the post to show the error I get in the simulator, but I don't know how to view all the errors in a log or the eclipse console

Comment: Do you have full stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

"Dialogs cannot be opened from a thread other than the main event thread"

`Synchronized` executes a statement in the current thread but holding the event lock, instead, `invokeAndWait`, sends the statement to an event queue to be executed later on the main event thread.

Thats why my code didn't work with `synchronized`

This helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6515542/1680787

@Nate, you are absolutly right about my catch blocks, +1 and my bad, just new to blackberry.

Comment: Gotcha.  So, the problem was actually calling `Dialog.alert()` from the background, but since you trapped that exception and didn't print it with your `catch(Exception e){}` handler, the system never propagated that error.  Your program must have then proceeded to have a **second**, possibly unrelated error, that was **not** caught, and resulted in you seeing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.    So, that was kind of a *red herring*.  Printing out exceptions in your catch handler would have shown: `java.lang.RuntimeException: pushModalScreen called by a non-event thread`