# loading/Welcome screen in BlackBerry during network connection for JDE 5

Tags: blackberry

Any body plz briefly explain and give the code how to make the loading screen and where to place the code, ie i mean how will the code know when to stop showing the display Screen and show the contents of the web ????? 
   I have tried the code given in StackoverFlow but it doesnot finds some class in JDE5

Answer (score 1):

```
Find this thread
```

[Blackberry - Loading/Wait screen with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801161/blackberry-loading-wait-screen-with-animation/3192169#3192169)
    this is the good example to show the please wait indicator.

OR

you can find the please wait project from below link

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/problem-in-gaugfield-show-urgent/td-p/964925

Comment: I have gone through the above code but it doesnot fully satisfy my purpose. So i m posting a new question explaining my problem regarding this.

Comment: Plz help ,, I had posted my problem again

Comment: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/problem-in-gaugfield-show-urgent/td-p/964925 you find one zip file ( PleaseWait.zip 7 KB) on this link. This is the complete source code to show the please wait indicator. Please try that code. I hope this is helpful for you.